Two column layout inside bslib card
I would like to use cards from the bslib package. Inside a card, I would like to have a two-column layout so this means for example two UI shiny elements side by side. Here I tried to create a simple reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(

        card(card_header("Test card"),
             sliderInput("bins",
                         "Number of bins:",
                         min = 1,
                         max = 50,
                         value = 30), 
             checkboxInput("Test", "Test checkbox", value = FALSE),
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Output:

As you can see the slider and checkbox are not side by side. I tried using fluidRow with two columns from the shinydashboard package. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to have UI elements side by side inside a card from the bslib package?

One option you can use is to surround your slider and text box with the function layout_column_wrap and add the argument width = 1/2.

Not sure about what you tried with shinydashboard columns but this works:
ui <- fluidPage(

  card(card_header("Test card"),
       fluidRow(
         column(width = 2,
                sliderInput("bins",
                            "Number of bins:",
                            min = 1,
                            max = 50,
                            value = 30)
         ),
         column(width = 2,
                checkboxInput("Test", "Test checkbox", value = FALSE))
                       ),

       plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
)


